# Add new column in pandas data frame based on condition and replace Nan values from different columns

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm trying to add a new column in a data frame based on certain conditions using numpy, so the frame looks like.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rawData = ({'a': [None,2,3], 'b': [5,6,8],'currency':['AUD','SA','NZD']})
df = pd.DataFrame(rawData)
print(df)

    a  b currency
0  NaN  5      AUD
1  2.0  6       SA
2  3.0  8      NZD
```

**adding column based on condition:**

```
mask1 = df['currency'].isin(['AUD'])
choice_mask1 = df['a']
mask2 = df['currency'].isin(['SA','NZD'])
choice_mask2= df['b']

df['c'] = np.select([mask1,mask2],[choice_mask1,choice_mask2],default = 0.00)

print(df)

  a  b currency    c
0  NaN  5      AUD  NaN
1  2.0  6       SA  6.0
2  3.0  8      NZD  8.0
```

So the output in **C** column is having NaN values, which I don't want. 
So if there is NaN in column a, Newly added column needs to consider the values from column b.

I'm very new while using numpy, so please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify the code

```
df['c'] = 0
cond = (df['currency'].isin(['AUD'])) & (df['a'].notnull())
df['c'] = np.where(cond, df['a'], df['b'])


    a   b   currency    c
0   NaN 5   AUD         5.0
1   2.0 6   SA          6.0
2   3.0 8   NZD         8.0
```

Edit: As @Ben.T pointed out, if you are looking at observations with different currency you need to tweak the conditions.

```
rawData = ({'a': [None,2,3, 5, 3], 'b': [5,6,8, 1,6],'currency':['AUD','SA','NZD', 'AUD', 'US']})
df = pd.DataFrame(rawData)

df['c'] = 0
cond1 = (df['currency'].isin(['AUD'])) & (df['a'].notnull())
cond2 = (df['currency'].isin(['SA','NZD'])) | (df['currency'].isin(['AUD'])) & (df['a'].isnull())

df.loc[cond1, 'c'] = df['a']
df.loc[cond2, 'c'] = df['b']

    a   b   currency    c
0   NaN 5   AUD         5.0
1   2.0 6   SA          6.0
2   3.0 8   NZD         8.0
3   5.0 1   AUD         5.0
4   3.0 6   US          0.0
```

OR using np.select

```
mask1 = (df['currency'].isin(['AUD'])) & (df['a'].notnull())
choice_mask1 = df['a']
mask2 = (df['currency'].isin(['SA','NZD'])) | (df['currency'].isin(['AUD'])) & (df['a'].isnull())
choice_mask2= df['b']

df['c'] = np.select([mask1,mask2],[choice_mask1,choice_mask2],default = 0.00)
```

Comment: This code is slightly different as the column `b` becomes the default value, not 0 as in the OP code. On the example data, it works as all rows meet one of the two conditions. Not sure it matters, just an observation :)

Comment: @Ben.T, the column c will take the value of column b only in case a is null. Check the code with the following df to see the output. rawData = ({'a': [None,2,3, 5], 'b': [5,6,8, 1],'currency':['AUD','SA','NZD', 'AUD']})
df = pd.DataFrame(rawData)

Comment: I agree with you that the code gives the column a in the case wanted, I was talking about if you have another currency than AUD, SA or NZD. According to the OP code, the value should be 0 while your code gives the column b. try with `rawData = ({'a': [None,2,3, 5], 'b': [5,6,8, 1],'currency':['AUD','SA','NZD', 'USD']})`. Should 0 but get 1 in column C last row. I know OP did not talk about that point, but it was to notice that the default value is not 0 anymore

Comment: @Ben.T, I agree, I just noticed that the code does not account for a different currency. Posting an edit. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

one possibility is to use `fillna` with value from the column `b` when creating `choice_mask1` such as

```
choice_mask1 = df['a'].fillna(df['b'])
```

and the rest is the same. Your output is then like:

```
     a  b currency    c
0  NaN  5      AUD  5.0
1  2.0  6       SA  6.0
2  3.0  8      NZD  8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

it's actually pretty straightforward using `combine_first`:

```
df['c'] = df.a.combine_first(df.b)
```

edit: this doesn't actually answer your question, as you seem to want to mask your results, so in that event, @ben.t's answer is better.